# Hello World in Ruby not outputting to terminal

Tags: ruby, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the Linux subsystem with the Ubuntu distribution for Windows 10 to interpret Ruby code. I have created a directory which contains a text file called `hello.rb` and placed inside of it:

```
puts "hello world"
```

I compile and run using `ruby hello.rb` and expected to get to my bash terminal the old greeting

```
hello world
```

Instead, I get no error but also no output. I should also add that:

```
ruby -e "puts 'Hello, world!'"
```

leads to an error:

```
-bash: !': event not found
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have confirmed that ruby is installed by typing `ruby -help` from bash and get the expected output.

Comment: It's hard to guess what your problem might be with running your file.  It 'should' work.  Try using irb and doing a ' load "hello.rb''' and see if you get any diagnostic.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not ruby, it is how bash make use of `!'`.

Your code is perfect, try simply deleting the exclamation mark [:

This is because you are trying to run it inline, you shouldn't have any problem in a `.rb` script!

Comment: ... or just swap the quotes around so that `bash` does not attempt to interpolate the string:  `ruby -e 'puts "Hello, world!"'`

Comment: @cdarke +1, at least untill he doesn't have some var

Answer (score 0):

As ingroxd said ! is special in bash, and double quotes are not sufficient to pass it verbatim to the command being executed. The solution is to escape ! separately at the top level:

```
$ ruby -e "puts 'Hello, world"\!"'"
Hello, world!
```